# How can I add Superuser role to internal user_system in Elasticsearch 7.7?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

ElasticsearchSecurityException was thrown when my monitor-plugin run in Elasticsearch 7.7.

Elasticsearch xpack security was open.
   config：
    xpack.security.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true

```
That exception thrown in the following code of :


private boolean isIndexExists() {
    IndicesExistsResponse response = nodeClient.admin().indices().prepareExists(MONITOR_INDEX).get();
    return response.isExists();
}



How can I add Superuser role to internal user_system?

org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: action [indices:admin/exists] is unauthorized for user [_system]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.support.Exceptions.authorizationError(Exceptions.java:34) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.denialException(AuthorizationService.java:597) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.authorizeSystemUser(AuthorizationService.java:388) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.authorize(AuthorizationService.java:190) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.authorizeRequest(SecurityActionFilter.java:172) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.lambda$applyInternal$3(SecurityActionFilter.java:158) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$writeAuthToContext$24(AuthenticationService.java:673) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.writeAuthToContext(AuthenticationService.java:687) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$handleNullToken$18(AuthenticationService.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.handleNullToken(AuthenticationService.java:576) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.consumeToken(AuthenticationService.java:439) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$extractToken$9(AuthenticationService.java:407) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.extractToken(AuthenticationService.java:427) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$checkForApiKey$3(AuthenticationService.java:368) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.ApiKeyService.authenticateWithApiKeyIfPresent(ApiKeyService.java:324) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.checkForApiKey(AuthenticationService.java:348) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$0(AuthenticationService.java:330) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.TokenService.getAndValidateToken(TokenService.java:396) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$2(AuthenticationService.java:326) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$lookForExistingAuthentication$6(AuthenticationService.java:386) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lookForExistingAuthentication(AuthenticationService.java:397) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.authenticateAsync(AuthenticationService.java:321) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.access$000(AuthenticationService.java:263) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:157) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.applyInternal(SecurityActionFilter.java:155) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:107) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

`elastic` is the inbuilt superuser in x-pack, Please refer official doc on [inbuilt user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html) from the doc

> The Elastic Stack security features provide built-in user credentials
>   to help you get up and running. These users have a fixed set of
>   privileges and cannot be authenticated until their passwords have been
>   set. The elastic user can be used to set all of the built-in user
>   passwords.

And about `elastic` superuser

> elastic A built-in superuser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But the internal user is different from the bulit-in user.How can I run my plugin with the elastic superuser？